# How can I stop the shopping cart to persist across store fronts in magento?

Tags: magento, internationalization, cart

I work for a web store selling fashion accessories, and they have one store front for their national site and another for international customers (without VAT).

Occasionally we get customers who order items in the national store because they are on sale and then check out in the international store (by changing store fronts with the standard store front switcher in magento).

If you go directly to the international site via URL, you get an empty shopping cart, but if you use the store front switcher the cart can persist with products from the other store that are not normally available in the international store. Does anyone know how to completely separate these, or empty the cart when switching store fronts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In admin, `System >> Configuration >> Web >> Session Validation Settings`,

set `Use SID on Frontend` to No.

But this will also logout customers coming from different store.

Comment: This works! Thanks for the heads up with the logouts, but that isn't an issue I think.

Answer (score 1):

Well If you create separate website with a single magento setup then customer will not be shared.
This also means that both sites will be independent of each other from customers perspective.

Can you confirm whether your stores are created as different website or same website but different stores.

Comment: They are the same website with different stores (with some products available in only one or the other store), they have separate domains but can be switched between using the store front switcher standard in Magento. The session setting above works, but thanks.

Comment: If you want to empty cart then why give link to switch stores.Or if you still want to give link pass an arg in the switch link that will be handled by controller events obsever class customized function and this function should empty cart.

Comment: That would probably work, the reason we have the switch is because the national domain name is reckognised more, so some of the internationals may go to that site initially. It is just to give them a way of navigating to the right place. So far I don't see any immediate disadvantages of just terminating the session when they switch stores, so I'll keep with it I think. Thanks for the tip.